# How to properly set PATH in PHP

Tags: php, environment-variables, fpm

I'm trying to set the `PATH` environment variable in PHP and am encountering some unexpected behaviour:

```
var_dump(getenv('PATH'));
system('echo $PATH');
system('which true 2>&1');
system('PATH="$PATH" which true 2>&1');
```

results in

```
string(23) "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
which: no true in ((null))
/usr/bin/true
```

This is also mirrored by the chosen executables which are from `/usr/bin` rather than `/usr/local/bin`.

My goal is (obviously) to change the path of some executable called during the script. But I can neither directly change the path of the executable whose path I want to change, because it is called indirectly by some binary. Nor can I simply use the `PATH="$PATH"` variant without patching an external library.

Because the obvious workarounds aren't applicable, and because I find this very curious, I'd like an explanation why this happens and how (or if) it is possible to set the PATH in a way that is passed down to `system` or `exec` calls.

The script is run via php-fpm, in case that's of interest here.

Comment: You're example doesn't seem consistent or reproducible.  If $PATH is properly set as shown in the 2nd line, the 3rd line should be working.  Are you sure lines 3 and 4 of the results aren't switched around?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, that's why I'm so puzzled by this, too.